# Bug: Scratch Orgs don't allow edits to User's Role

Tags: scratch-org

I'm not sure what the issue is here but I want to report it to determine if it's just for me or if it is a known issue with DX at the moment. Every scratch org I spin up, when I attempt to modify a user's role I get the following error:

[image]

[image]

It seems I can edit other trivial fields on the user, but Role is some how off limits. And from what I can tell some of the roles of my users was lost when spinning up the scratch org hence my attempt to edit it in the first place.

Anyways else having this issue or have any idea what other factors may be involved?

Comment: Have you tried opening a case with support?

Comment: Not yet, I wanted to see if any one had similar issues first. Every case I've opened with Salesforce has ended in some form of frustration that I'm trying to avoid at the moment.

Comment: You have a Gack. You'll need to contact Support. It's not *supposed* to be doing that; I've edited roles plenty of times in my various tests.

Comment: Seems like this is still the case - can't set a role on a user in a scratch org. Bump!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's a [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000018BvaQAE).

> Workaround: Contact Salesforce support and reference internal article
>   000269858 to have the issue resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing an issue while setting up a community on the Scratch org. So, I created a new role at the root level and add a user into that role. By this, I can assign a role to a user. So, it looks like an issue with the Standard Roles in scratch org.